# Exsys Corvid Core

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Is anyone using the Exsys Corvid Expert System? I'm working on a diagnostic system using the confidence factors shown below. The system asks a series of questions, then uses the sum of the confidence factors to arrive at the top recommendations.

However, we encountered the situation where some of the factors really need to have greater weights than others in some cases. Any recommendations or ideas on handling different weights?

- Definitely: 1.0
- Almost Certainly: 0.8
- Probably: 0.6
- Maybe: 0.4
- Unknown: -0.2 to 0.2
- Maybe Not: -0.4
- Probably Not: -0.6
- Almost Certainly Not: -0.8
- Definitely Not: -1.0

Answer (score 0):

I use Corvid. If "definitely not" means that this factor rules out the particular choice or option, you should be using something like -500 for the weight. same for "definitely yes" but in reverse. and so forth.